# Custom react-admin resource pages

Tags: react-admin

Is it possible to have custom "verbs" in addition to the default CRUD `list/create/edit/show`? I have other record-related actions (`.../listen`, `.../watch`, `.../read`, etc.) and would like to use the existing system rather than trying to blindly hack something on top. Just adding entries to an index page, eg.

```
export default {
  edit: ContentEdit,
  list: ContentList,
  show: ContentShow,
  watch: ContentWatch,
  icon: ContentIcon,
};
```

like there are for the default verbs silently goes to the `/edit` view.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you'll have to use custom routes for that